# Passing the same env to both envir and enclos in eval?

Tags: r, eval

Here is a snippet from magrittr package:

```
`%>%` <-
  function(lhs, rhs)
  {

      browser()

    # Capture unevaluated arguments
    lhs <- substitute(lhs)
    rhs <- substitute(rhs)

    # Should rhs be evaluated first due to parentheses?
    if (is.call(rhs) && identical(rhs[[1]], quote(`(`)))
      rhs <- eval(rhs, parent.frame(), parent.frame())
    ......
}
```

Now here is the doc on eval:

```
Usage:

     eval(expr, envir = parent.frame(),
                enclos = if(is.list(envir) || is.pairlist(envir))
                            parent.frame() else baseenv())

Arguments:

    expr: an object to be evaluated.  See ‘Details’.

   envir: the ‘environment’ in which ‘expr’ is to be evaluated.  May
          also be ‘NULL’, a list, a data frame, a pairlist or an
          integer as specified to ‘sys.call’.

  enclos: Relevant when ‘envir’ is a (pair)list or a data frame.
          Specifies the enclosure, i.e., where R looks for objects not
          found in ‘envir’.  This can be ‘NULL’ (interpreted as the
          base package environment, ‘baseenv()’) or an environment.
```

So the author passed parent.frame() to both envir and enclos, i.e., if you can't find some object in parent.frame(), look in it again. I don't know what's the point here.

Comment: So what? What I was implying is: this thing doesn't look very logical, but if Hadley is a co-author, there might be a good reason of doing so, and I would like to know that reason. Why is this a problem?

Comment: I think the idea is that if it's not in `parent.frame()`, don't look anywhere else.

Comment: I know. Suggestions already accepted.

Comment: The name of the package is magrittr, not migrittr.